# how to add commas to a number in swift?

Tags: swift

How would I add commas to a number that I'm retrieving from a JSON in swift.

```
Example
31908551587 to
31,908,551,587
```

I'm so confused and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 212):

You can do it with `NSNumberFormatter`

**Swift 4**

```
let largeNumber = 31908551587
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:largeNumber))
```

**Swift 3**

```
 let largeNumber = 31908551587
 let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
 numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
 let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:largeNumber))
```

**Swift 2**

```
 let largeNumber = 31908551587
 let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
 numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
 let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(largeNumber)
```

Comment: is there any way for doing like this '31,90,85,51,587' using NumberFormatter?

Comment: @SanketBhavsar i don't think so [check](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter.style)

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil I did it with currency(style)

Comment: how to do reverse

Comment: Is there any way to convert 1000000000000000 to 1,000,000,000,000,000 ?? Because these works for seven 0 after the number...

Comment: maybe its too late but you can use "EN-IN" local for it. @Sanlet_B

Comment: @Sanket_B, have you considered adding an answer on that?

Answer (score 68):

Expanding on Özgür Ersil's answer, you can isolate the functionality with an extesion to Int:

```
extension Int {
    func withCommas() -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:self))!
    }
}
```

To then use on your code as:

```
largeNumber.withCommas()
```

Comment: Is this adding a comma to you guys? For me it's adding dots...

Comment: Works great, best answer on the page. @lopes710 adds commas, not dots for me

Answer (score 16):

Also expanding on Juan Fran Jimenez's answer, I would recommend putting the formatter into a singleton, since instantiating a formatter is usually a relatively expensive operation. (It could affect the performance if you're formatting on-the-go as the user writes.)

```
extension Int {

    private static var commaFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()

    internal var commaRepresentation: String {
        return Int.commaFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I would consider doing `?? "\(self)"` instead of returning an empty string.

Answer (score 9):

A simple drop in extension that will provide a variable via an extension of `Int`.

As noted in Julien's answer, this makes use of a static formatter for performance reasons.

```
extension Int {
    private static var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

        return numberFormatter
    }()

    var delimiter: String {
        return Int.numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
let number = 31908551587
print(number.delimiter) // 31,908,551,587
```

Comment: ??? Your code is practically identical to Julien's answer. The only thing different is he has `internal var` and you just have `var`. What does your answer add to the conversation? Also, I would say your variable `delimiter` is misleading. Julien's `commaRepresentation` is much more useful.

Answer (score 6):

This is an additional way of setting comma position. Let's say I want the number 10000000 to be printed as "1,00,00,000"

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
numberFormatter.secondaryGroupingSize = 2
numberFormatter.string(from: 10000000)
```

Comment: this code is not working when number contain dot 10000000.12

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

If you want to use it for label:

```
private func formatNumberToThousand(number: Int) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = "."
    let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))
    return formattedNumber ?? ""
}
```

to use it:

```
let thousand = 193843
yourLabel.text = formatNumberToThousand(number: thousand)
//Output: 193.843
```

Comment: It looks like decimal, not comma

Answer (score 1):

I have created a class for amount textfield. Simply set it to your textfield class. 
Ex- Enter 1234567. It will convert it to 1,234,567
Also work for decimal entry, will take two digits after decimal.

```
class AmountField: UITextField {

private var isFirstDecimal : Bool = true
override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {

    addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    keyboardType = .decimalPad
    textAlignment = .left
    placeholder = "0.0"
    editingChanged()
}
override func deleteBackward() {
    var currentText = self.text ?? ""
    currentText = String(currentText.dropLast())
    self.text = currentText
    editingChanged(self)
}
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField? = nil) {
    var doubleStr = textField?.text ?? "00"


    let decimalCount = doubleStr.components(separatedBy: ".")
    if decimalCount.count > 2 {
        var currentText = self.text ?? ""
        currentText = String(currentText.dropLast())
        self.text = currentText
        return
    }

    if doubleStr.contains(".") && isFirstDecimal == true {
        self.text = doubleStr
        isFirstDecimal = false
        return
    }
    else if !(doubleStr.contains(".")) {
        isFirstDecimal = true
    }

    let doubleStrTemp = doubleStr.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

    if doubleStrTemp != "" {
        if let n = Decimal(string: doubleStrTemp )?.significantFractionalDecimalDigits {
            if n > 2 {
                var currentText = self.text ?? ""
                currentText = String(currentText.dropLast())
                self.text = currentText
                return
            }
        }
    }
    doubleStr = doubleStr.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

    let doube = Double(doubleStr)
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    if doube != nil {
        let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:doube!))
        self.text = formattedNumber
    }
}}

extension Decimal {
var significantFractionalDecimalDigits: Int {
    return max(-exponent, 0)
}}
```

Comment: No I am using NSNumberFormatter. For decimal and other validation I put separate conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
let largeNumber = 31908551587
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:largeNumber))
```