# Adding commas to number values as user types in the UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift3, nsnumberformatter, uitextfielddelegate

I am using an altered method to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021197/how-to-add-commas-to-a-number-in-swift) where I want to format a `UITextField` as the user is typing in the number. As in I want the number being live-formatted. I am looking to change 1000 to 1,000, 50000 to 50,000 and so on.

My issue is that my `UITextField` values are not updating as expected. For instance, when I type in 50000 in the `UITextField` the result is coming back as 5,0000 instead of 50,000. Here is my code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    //check if any numbers in the textField exist before editing
    guard let textFieldHasText = (textField.text), !textFieldHasText.isEmpty else {
        //early escape if nil
        return true
    }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal

    //remove any existing commas
    let textRemovedCommma = textFieldHasText.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

    //update the textField with commas
    let formattedNum = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textRemovedCommma)!))
    textField.text = formattedNum
    return true
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int/34294660?s=1|0.1034#34294660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule number 1 of `shouldChangeCharactersIn` - If you assign a value to the text field's `text` property you must return `false`. Returning `true` tells the text field to make the original change to the text that you have already modified. That is not what you want.

You have one other major flaw in your code. It won't work in locales that use other ways to format larger numbers. Not all locales use a comma as the group separator.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize I was using the true/false return incorrectly. And thanks for catching the locale issue. I'll try to fix this and I will report back !

Answer (score 1):

Try using **NSNumberFormatter**.

```
var currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
// localize to your grouping and decimal separator
currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
var priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99)
```

It will print value like = **"$9,999.99"**

You can also set the **Locale** as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
let textRemovedCommma = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
let formattedNum = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textRemovedCommma!)!))
textField.text = formattedNum
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using decimal style use currency style. Also set currencySymbol empty string if you don't need  it. Also make sure your device region is selected as India other wise it will add commas after 3 digit instead of 2 digits.

```
 -(NSString*)addingCommasToFloatValueString:(NSString *)rupeeValue 
{
NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[rupeeValue   doubleValue]];
NSNumberFormatter *aFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[aFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[aFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
[aFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[aFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *formattedNumber = [aFormatter stringFromNumber:aNumber];
return formattedNumber;
}
```