# Adding thousands separators to UILabel numbers

Tags: ios, swift, int, uilabel, calculator

I'm trying to add thousands separators on the numbers exporting out of two `UILabel`s on my code. I've already searched for it on here but none works for my project.
here's the part about calculation in my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userCount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var projectAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func polculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let usersCount = Double(self.userCount.text ?? "") ?? 0
        let commissionPercentage = 0.26

        let projectsAmount = Double(self.projectAmount.text ?? "") ?? 0

        let totalsLabel = (usersCount * projectsAmount)
        self.totalLabel.text = "\(totalsLabel)"

        let resultsLabel = (usersCount * commissionPercentage * projectsAmount)
        self.resultLabel.text = "\(resultsLabel)"
    }
}
```

What code should I add here?

Comment: Hint: `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add commas to a number in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021197/how-to-add-commas-to-a-number-in-swift)